# Issue sending -> encrypting -> getting with jQuery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, encryption

I have a php file where I receive 4 parameters (via $_GET) and I want to generate and encrypted string with those values, I have this code:

```
$key="asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf";
$result = '';
for($i=0; $i<strlen($cadena); $i++) {
    $char = substr($cadena, $i, 1);
    $keychar= substr($key, ($i % strlen($key))-1, 1);
    $char = chr(ord($char)+ord($keychar));
    $result.=$char;
}
echo base64_encode($result);
//and later I generate de JSON object
```

And I´m trying to get that value with jQuery, using this code:

```
$.getJSON( urlBase+"getSeed.php", { hours: this.hours, minutes: this.minutes, seconds:this.seconds, score: this.score })
.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    alert( "Oooops, something hapenned with the request... " + error );
}
);
```

If write the url with the values (http://www.whatever.com/php/getSeed.php?hours=15&minutes=39&seconds=5&score=10867) I get the right value in the screen, but when I try to get it from jQuery (the second code block) I´m getting an error every single time.

I don´t know too much about PHP, actually I know just superbasic stuff but I´m not being able to fix this, can someone tell me what is hapenning here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check that the correct request is sent by looking into the network tab in the developer tools.

Comment: I did it and everything is ok. As I said, if I write that URL in Chrome I can see the result perfectly, the problem is when I make that request in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to:

1. double check (via inspecting the response at your script's URL) that the JSON is syntactically correct.
2. add "Content-Type: application/json" header to your script.

   `// before printing out your json:
   @header('Content-Type: application/json');
   // your JSON output goes here`

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure at all about the problem (probably generating the JSON) but I fixed it doing something that I should do before... I returned the info as a plain string (instead of a JSON object) and changed the getJSON for a normal $.get